# How to determine if calling a function requires administrative privileges

Tags: windows, function, uac, administrator, elevated-privileges

I am trying to find out if there is an easy way to tell if calling a function will require my program to be run as an administrator in order to work properly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Certainly. You can run the function, and if it fails with `GetLastError() == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, then you needed administrative privileges.

Comment: Does GetLastError() remove the retrieved error from the list of previous errors...will subsequent calls to GetLastError() repeatedly return the same last error until another error occurs?

Comment: Is there any way to determine which functions require administrative privileges without actually running a test program on it...aka someway to parse through the source code, and look for specific sections that require heightened access. For example, is there a list of specific Win32 API functions that require administrative access in order to successfully call? Thanks!

Comment: No, there's no actual list, because in nearly all cases it depends on the arguments, and on what the arguments represent. For example, `CreateFile` may or may not require admin access, depending on which file you're trying to open, and what the ACL on that file is. So either you need to go read the description of the function to see if it accesses anything with an ACL or requires special token rights, or you can just run the thing and see if it bails out on you.

Comment: And the conditions under which the error code can change are documented in the msdn page for `GetLastError()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679360(v=vs.85).aspx . GetLastError() itself does not alter the last-error code